# Could somebody help me out by telling me how to convert Actionscript 2 to actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I devised a simple game that is at mice using actionscript 3. I do not understand how to change the code of actionscript 2 to actionscript 3, please help me.

Could somebody help me out by telling me how to convert Actionscript 2 to actionscript3 ?

```
jumlah = 0;
waktu_muncul = 0;

function buat_tikus() 
 {
   nomor = random(3)+1;

tikus=attachMovie("tikus","tikus",2{_x:_root["lingkaran"+nomor]._x,_y:_root["lingkaran"+nomor]._y});

tikus.onEnterFrame = function() 
{
    waktu_muncul++;
    if (waktu_muncul == 0)
{
        this.gotoAndStop(4);
}
    if (waktu_muncul == 20) 
    {
        removeMovieClip(this);
        buat_tikus();
        waktu_muncul = 2;
    }
    tikus.onPress = function() 
    {
        sound1 = new Sound();
        sound1.attachSound("Suaratikus");
        sound1.start(0,1);
        var tikus:MovieClip;


    if (jumlah == 90) 
    {
      stop();
    nextFrame();
    }
        if (this._currentframe == 1) 
        {
            jumlah += 10;
            this.gotoAndPlay(2);
         }
     };
 };
}

onEnterFrame = function () 
{
 fps++;
 if (fps == 20) 
  {
    timer_txt--;
    fps=0
       if (timer_txt==0)
         {
          stop();
          gotoAndStop(6);
          }
         }

palu.swapDepths(_root.getNextHighestDepth());
palu._x = _xmouse;
palu._y = _ymouse;
};

  onMouseDown = function () 
   {
      if (palu._currentframe == 1) 
      {
      palu.gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
 };

buat_tikus();

var fps : Number = 0;
var timer_txt : Number = 20;
```

Comment: There's no converting AS2 to AS3, those are 2 different languages.

Comment: The syntax of AS2 and AS3 are similar but the direct coupling of AS2 data types to Flash were removed. There are a number of references that can help in the migration process; http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/first_as3_application.html and http://cis.msjc.edu/courses/Internet_Authoring/CSIS119A/Resources/langref/migration.html (not sure where(if) that document exists on Adobe site anymore) are a good place to start.

Comment: I think that this code is `AS1`. In `AS2` and `AS3` the `random` global function was removed in **Flash Player 5** in favor of `random` method of the `Math` Class. Please, build the App from the scratch, because `AS1` is an old, old language an is completely (radically) different of `AS3`.

Comment: Yes there's some similarities between AS2 and AS3 but still not similar enough to make a conversion easy. A line by line conversion would still very likely be not enough to make the entire thing work. The entire event system will have to be reworked, adding/removing children will have to be reworked and validated, etc ... at the end you end up with a maybe working project at best. Starting over is the only way to get a good running app.

Comment: Thanks for your explain BotMaster and Elchiininet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BotMaster's response to this question is right on the money; not to belabor the point, but I have been in this person's shoes, and I can understand the frustration of migrating from AS2 to AS3. Long term: Learn AS3. Short Term: if you have this game, and somehow you need to make it work ASAP (learning AS3 will take some time), one thing you might try is to create an empty AS3 swf that loads your complete game. That might work (but like I said, long term AS3 is more powerful).

Also, depending on how you created the game, you might try the Google Swiffy extension which might convert some basic AS2 games. Note that it WONT convert as2 to as3 but it might make the game accessible on the web. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

To be clear on AS2/AS3 conversion. This is not possible, those are 2 different languages and their keywords/global methods/properties/event system/display list, etc ... do not match and for that reason are incompatible. That is why for example there's no tool that exist that can convert in one click of a button a AS2 code to a AS3 code. 
There are similarities though in those 2 languages and some pieces of AS2 code can sometimes work as is in AS3, other pieces of code can sometimes be converted quite easily, and of course other pieces of code cannot at all be converted and a new AS3 code has to replace the old AS2 code.

All in all only a translation can be done between the two languages and this has to be done line by line. Evaluating if the line is compatible and if it's not replacing it with something that will work in AS3, etc ...

To add to the difficulty some AS2 projects can have code placed inside symbols all over the place. In that case a translation to AS3 will be very unlikely to achieve.

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation BotMaster, can you help me to make the script as 3, the game that I will make has a 3 "hole" as a movie clip, then the "rat" as a movie clip will be out randomly over the movie "hole". I am very confused on ActionScript 3. please.